# Should I use price, cost, or rate when referring to rent?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Example:

> I don't know which apartment to choose. The *price/rate/cost* in this city is just insane.

What the most appropriate option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, without further context I would understand the terms this way:

*Price* is to purchase the apartment outright. e.g. *"The prices for apartments in this city are insane."*

*Rate* is paid every week/fortnight/month for the rent. e.g. *"The rental rates in this city are insane."*

*Cost* might be understood to refer to general cost of living expenses, e.g. *"The costs in this city are insane."*

So, Rate - but I would use the more specific term *rent* if that's what you're referring to. e.g. *"The rents in this city are insane."*

On the other hand, in a city where the majority of apartments are very expensive and generally rented, and if you appear to be a student of low means, I would understand your *"prices"* to mean rents, but this is making an assumption.

Comment: +1 for the alternative but idiomatic "The rents in this city are insane."